# Can a not removed ViewTreeObserver listener cause memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm listening to layout changes of a view using an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener);
```

Since I'm interested in the events of this listener as long as the view exists I see no need to call `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener)`.

Can this cause memory leaks or is the listener garbage collected along with the view? Assume that the listener holds a reference to the view.

---

The backgound is that I want to create a module that can be attached to certain views and does stuff based on layout changes. If removing is not necessary its creation would be just as simple as `new FancyModule(theView)` and the constructor then takes care of binding the listener. If removal is necessary I'd have to implement a destructor method which I'd like to prevent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potential memory leak depends only on your architecture.

Normally, it's fine not to call `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener)`.
`View` holds reference to `ViewTreeObserver` which holds reference to added `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. If you don't have another reference to the listener, it's garbage collected along the view.

Now, if your implementation of `OnGlobalLayoutListener` holds reference to the view it is still fine. A reference cycle is not a problem for Android's garbage collector.

A problem can be created if you have another component that holds reference to the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` implementation. If the component lives longer than the view (e.g. it is held via the application object) then you create a memory leak of the view (and context) through the listener.

It is important to not hold the view when it's no longer used. A simple way how to avoid leaking the view is to use `WeakReference`.

Comment: The listener and view only hold a cyclic reference to each other. No other component is involved. I wasn't sure if a view's `getViewTreeObserver()` could possibly return objects living longer than the view itself.

Comment: Well, if nothing else holds the reference cycle from outside then it's ok.

Comment: This is totally wrong IMO. Listeners are added to the ViewRoot tree observer, so your view might be collected, but the root view might not. This is easy to reproduce.

Comment: "I wasn't sure if a view's getViewTreeObserver() could possibly return objects living longer than the view itself." -> It does @McFarlane

Answer (score 7):

I had the same memory leak problem, I tried to unregister OnGlobalLayoutListener in onDestroyView in the fragment but the problem still existed, then I tried to add onDetachListener for my view and then unregister OnGlobalLayoutListener and it's worked.

In kotlin I used:

```kotlin
view?.doOnDetach {
    onGlobalLayoutListener?.let {
        view?.viewTreeObserver?.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(it)
    }
    onGlobalLayoutListener = null
}
```

You can use the addOnAttachStateChangeListener method too.

Comment: I've tried other solutions but none worked (remove onDestroy, onDestroyView, onDetach), finally have to convert my class from Java to Kotlin in order to use doOnDetach since it is part of the Kotlin extension, and finally solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: that helped me, I was having this issue within a Composable, trying to use `DisposableEffect` and calling `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` within the `onDispose` but it is too late and the viewTreeObserver instance kept getting leaked.

using this `doOnDetach` did it for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can leak. Here's an example trace from LeakCanary,

- com.xxx.Activity has leaked:
- GC ROOT static android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.sInstance
- references android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
- references com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.mAttachInfo
- references android.view.View$AttachInfo.mTreeObserver
- references android.view.ViewTreeObserver.mOnGlobalLayoutListeners
- references android.view.ViewTreeObserver$CopyOnWriteArray.mData
- references java.util.ArrayList.elementData
- references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
- references com.xxx.Activity$setExpandedToolbarHeight$layoutListener$1.this$0 (anonymous implementation of android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)
- leaks com.xxx.Activity instance

Comment: Can you extend your answer with code snippets showing how you've used the listener?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same memory leak problem and even though I removed the `onGlobalLayoutListener` in `onDetachedFromWindow` the leak still ocurred:

```kotlin
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow() 
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener); 
}

override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {  
    view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener); 
    super.onDetachedFromWindow() 
}
```

Then I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248025/4891063) on the similar question:

> Since you are using a ViewTreeObserver of a child view, the behavior is slightly more complex and one possible solution would involve adding an OnAttachStateChangeListener to your scrollView and add/remove your OnScrollChangedListener from there.

> Anyway in regard of the reason why there was a leak:
> getViewTreeObserver() is not going to return the same instance after
> the View has been detached from the window. Calling
> removeOnScrollChangedListener() may have no effect, keeping your
> original OnScrollChangedListener still attached to the old
> ViewTreeObserver, and so leaking your Context.

Using `OnAttachStateChangeListener` on the `view` and removing the listener as suggested didn't help, so, the solution was to use the `ViewTreeObserver` of the activity's root view:

```kotlin
private val activityRootView: View = (context as Activity).window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content)

override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow() 
    activityRootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener); 
}

override fun onDetachedFromWindow() { 
    activityRootView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(myListener);
    super.onDetachedFromWindow() 
}
```

and the leak didn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not so simple but this is the point:

1. Do viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener) just after or when view is already attached
2. Do viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener) on detach

My implementation uses classes from `Renetik Framework` but can give more interesting points to remember here:

```
fun View.onGlobalLayout(function: (CSRegistration) -> void): CSRegistration {
    lateinit var registration: CSRegistration
    val listener = OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        if (registration.isActive) function(registration)
    }

    fun attach() = viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    fun detach() = viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)

    val attachStateListener = object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) = attach()
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) = detach()
    }
    addOnAttachStateChangeListener(attachStateListener)

    registration = CSRegistration(
        onResume = { if (isAttachedToWindow) attach() },
        onPause = { detach() },
        onCancel = { removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(attachStateListener) }
    ).start()
    return registration
}
```